# Always Encrypted - Lock request time out period exceeded

Tags: azure-sql-database, always-encrypted

I'm trying to encrypt a column and am getting the following error: `Set-SqlColumnEncryption : Lock request time out period exceeded.` Are there parameters to specify the lock timeout? What could be locking it? The table has about 10k records. It works fine with empty tables or tables with hundreds of records.

Comment: Try turning off any applications or users that may be doing frequent queries on that table. The latter of the two may be easier said than done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can't have certain options turned on for the table, like "large value types out of row". Here's what I did:

`exec sys.sp_tableoption
    @TableNamePattern = 'dbo.SomeTableName'
    ,@OptionName = 'large value types out of row'
    ,@OptionValue = 'off';`